# Mac : Unable to open uiautomatorviewer on Mac High Seirra

Tags: android, macos

Unable to open uiautomatorviewer on mac,

Below is log from terminal

```
/Users/ranjith/Library/Android/sdk/tools_mac/tools/uiautomatorviewer ; exit;
Ranjiths-MacBook-Pro-2:~ ranjith$ /Users/ranjith/Library/Android/sdk/tools_mac/tools/uiautomatorviewer ; exit;
-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/ranjith/Library/Android/sdk/tools_mac/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/ranjith/Library/Android/sdk/tools_mac/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Looks like your java is not properly installed

Comment: Ranjiths-MacBook-Pro-2:lib ranjith$ java -version
java version "10" 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)

Comment: Try downgrading to `java 8` instead which is the LTS release as well that should solve the problem

Comment: I'm new to mac, could you please explain me steps

Comment: to completely uninstall java follow the commands as mentioned on [official website](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) after this grab the latest java 8 version and install it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue by below steps

- installed java 8
- navigated to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and deleted default version of java(java 10)

it worked